# Determining complex function f(z), properties are given ... Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to determine the complex function $f(z)$ which has the following properties:

- $\lim\limits_{ z\to\infty} f(z)=3$
- $f$ is everywhere analytic except for two singularities:
      a pole of first order in $z=−1$ with residue $2$ and
      a pole of second order in $z=0$ with residue $−1$
- $f(1)=1$

The denominator should be $(z+1)*z^2$ because of of the poles which are given. According to Liouville the numerator is a polynomial.

For the mathematician this would take probably less than 5 minutes, I can't solve this one so please help me out. Even if you give the final answer I will find the steps myself if that is an issue... Hope someone will reply thanks !

Comment: What can you say about the numerator (the polynomial)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have a few terms from the second statement:

$\dfrac{2}{z+1},\dfrac{-1}{z}, \dfrac{A}{z^2}$

Since these terms do not contribute to limit of 3, just add 3.

Then we must calculate $A$ to have $f(1) = 1 - 1 + A + 3 = 1 $, so $A = -2$, so the final result:

$$ f(z) = 3 - \dfrac{2}{z^2} - \dfrac{1}{z} + \dfrac{2}{z+1}  $$

Comment: I finally understand it, thank you very much !